# what are curl default timeouts in linux

Tags: linux, networking, curl

my question is different from [Does curl have a timeout?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94604/does-curl-have-a-timeout), because that question is related to set timeouts to curl command. But my question is not to set timeouts, I want to know default behavior of these timeouts for a curl command.

What are the default timeouts (`connect-timeout` and `max-time`) of a curl command in `linux`, where they are configured and can we edit them. And is there any configuration available in our local machine where we can change for all curl commands from that machine instead of setting timeouts for each and every curl command

Comment: Have a look at **Defaults** section in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94612/259047).